# Bluetooth headset in-call volume doesn't change?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, motorola-droid, volume-control

I have a Motorola Droid (the original, A855) and a Jawbone Icon bluetooth headset. The headset does not have its own volume controls, so I've tried adjusting the volume using the volume rocker. While the on-screen display shows BlueTooth volume as what's being adjusted, the volume seems to be exactly the same when turned all the way down or all the way up.

Is this just an issue with the Icon, the Droid, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating your Jawbone's firmware and see if that fixes it.  You can also try installing [Jawbone Companion](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jawbone.companion) and see if that helps.  It doesn't have the OG Droid listed as being compatible when I click on Install on the Google Play site, it has my OG Droid as one of the options so it's worth a shot.